# How to make edittext editable after clicking on edit button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a user profile screen in my android app and there i am showing user information while registering they provided and a edit button to modify their information.

Comment: What is your question? `EditText` is editable by default.

Comment: i was required to make it editable only on click of button below that EditText else it will not be focusable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable it in your xml

```
android:editable="false" 
android:inputType="none"
```

And enable it programatically in the `onClick()` of the edit `Button`

```
EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
mEdit.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i've updated my answer. So set it at false in the xml, so it starts up uneditable, and change it with the code setEnabled, when your button is beeing pressed.

Answer (score 5):

```
edT.setFocusable(false); //to disable it

 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      edT.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); //to enable it
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

android:editable is deprecated.

Use only `android:focusable="false"` in xml.

And on button click -

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.yourid);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code : It handles edit and done both events.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText edtText;
private Button btnEdit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtText = findViewById(R.id.edtTxt);
    btnEdit = findViewById(R.id.btnEdt);

    edtText.setEnabled(false);
    btnEdit.setText("Edit");

    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnEdt:  //Your edit button
            enableDisableEditText();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

//method for enable or disable edittext
private void enableDisableEditText() {
    if (edtText.isEnabled()) {
        edtText.setEnabled(false);
        btnEdit.setText("Edit");
    } else {
        edtText.setEnabled(true);
        btnEdit.setText("Done");
    }
}
```

}

*Happy coding..*